# Update text on a buttonfield when it is clicked

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to set the text on a button when it is clicked. I'm initialising a BigVector which will update the text of the button with its value. I'm using a counter value to determine wihcih BigVector value should be selected. The problem is, the below code is expecting the counter value to be final.

A better methodology for updating the text on a Field when it is clicked is most welcome.

Here is my code -

```
    final BigVector bigStringVectorA = new BigVector();
    bigStringVectorA.addElement("A Test answer 1");
    bigStringVectorA.addElement("A Test answer 2");
    bigStringVectorA.addElement("A Test answer 3");

    aAnswerOptionButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {  
         public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {  
            aAnswerOptionButton.setText((String)bigStringVectorA.elementAt(counter));
        }
   });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the counter an instance variable, either in the outer class or in the anonymous FieldChangeListener:

```
aAnswerOptionButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
  private int counter = 0;
  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    counter++;
    if (counter > bigStringVectorA.size()) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    aAnswerOptionButton.setText((String)bigStringVectorA.elementAt(counter));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the invalidate() method of that field and that should force the redraw of that button.

```
aAnswerOptionButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {  
         public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {  
            aAnswerOptionButton.setText((String)bigStringVectorA.elementAt(counter));
            aAnswerOptionButton.invalidate();
        }
   });
```